# How to add <li> element from code behind using a method in the front end.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to use a method to add some

elements inside . I am using following code:

```
<ul id="testul" runat="server">
  <%# LoadModalForm(testul) %>
</ul>
```

Code Behind:

```
 protected Control LoadModalForm(Control ulCtrl)
        {

            var li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");

            // creating link with href
            var lnk = new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = "#modal-editprofile" };

            lnk.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "modal");
            lnk.Text = "Edit";
            li.Controls.Add(lnk);


            ulCtrl.Controls.Add(li);

            return ulCtrl;

        }
```

But I am getting exception:

```
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases.
```

**Details:**

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases.]
   System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child) +12283968
```

Comment: I think you can use Literal control and from code behind set the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul id="testul" runat="server">

</ul>
```

code behind :

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadModalForm(testul);
        }

        protected void LoadModalForm(Control ulCtrl)
        {

            var li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");

            // creating link with href
            var lnk = new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = "#modal-editprofile" };

            lnk.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "modal");
            lnk.Text = "Edit";
            li.Controls.Add(lnk);


            ulCtrl.Controls.Add(li);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the function call just:

```
<ul id="testul" runat="server">

</ul>
```

Then in an event like Page_Load

```
 LoadModalForm(testul);
```

You don't need to return anything from LoadModalForm, it already adds the child control.